# MySQL JSON find multiple values

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a table and in one column I have weekdays as JSON data. I'm trying a query to get results if it has one or more than one day that matches the user selection.

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL, label VARCHAR(16), data VARCHAR(80));

INSERT INTO test VALUES
    (null, 'test 1', '["Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"]'),
    (null, 'test 2', '["Thursday", "Friday"]'),
    (null, 'test 3', '["Sunday", "Saturday", "Monday"]');
```

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$[*]')) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

The query was supposed to give me test 1 and test 2 as result.

Here is the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fC48mHEM1nuLUZCTP8CLfs/43).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` to do it

```
SELECT * FROM test
where JSON_CONTAINS(data,'"Monday"')=1 or JSON_CONTAINS(data,'"Tuesday"')
```

**[Working demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fC48mHEM1nuLUZCTP8CLfs/44)**

If you do not want to use `OR`,then you can try **[json-overlaps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps)** like below:

```
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
      JSON_OVERLAPS(data,'["Monday","Tuesday"]')=1
```

But be careful that it only support starting with MySQL 8.0.17

Comment: These days will be entered by the user. This way I need to add OR dynamically in the query. Any other option?

Comment: @Omer you can use [json-overlaps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps) to do it

Comment: json-overlaps only display one result. `SELECT * FROM test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data,'["Monday","Tuesday"]')=1`

Comment: its not working on DB Fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fC48mHEM1nuLUZCTP8CLfs/45

Comment: @Omer `JSON_CONTAINS` doesn't support this type of query,using `JSON_OVERLAPS` instead, and sorry for typo in my answer

Comment: **#1305 - FUNCTION db_test.JSON_OVERLAPS does not exist** 

Comment: @Omer see the last part of my answer,**But be careful that it only support starting with MySQL 8.0.17**

Comment: I guess I have to use OR  I'll wait for more answers but I guess your answer seems like the only way for now.